# Use dictionary data to append data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a `dataframe` and 2 separate `dictionaries`. Both dictionaries have the same keys but have different values. `dict_1` has key-value pairs where the values are unique ids that correspond with the dataframe `df`. I want to be able to use the 2 dictionaries and the unique ids from the `dict_1` to append the values of `dict_2` into the dataframe `df`.

Example of dataframe `df`:

```
col_1    col_2    id   col_3
 100      500     a1    478
 785      400     a1    490
 ...      ...     a1    ...
 ...      ...     a2    ...
 ...      ...     a2    ...
 ...      ...     a2    ...
 ...      ...     a3    ...
 ...      ...     a3    ...
 ...      ...     a3    ...
 ...      ...     a4    ...
 ...      ...     a4    ...
 ...      ...     a4    ...
```

Example of `dict_1`:

```
1:['a1', 'a3'],
2:['a2', 'a4'],
3:[...],
4:[...],
5:[...],
.
```

Example of `dict_2`:

```
1:[0, 1],
2:[1, 1],
3:[...],
4:[...],
5:[...],
.
```

I'm trying to append the data from `dict_2` using id's from `dict_1` into the main `df`.
In a sense add the 2 values (or n values) from the lists of `dict_2` as 2 columns (or n columns) into the `df`.

Resultant `df`:

```
col_1    col_2    id   col_3   new_col_1   new_col_2 
 100      500     a1    478        0           1
 785      400     a1    490        0           1
 ...      ...     a1    ...        0           1
 ...      ...     a2    ...        1           1
 ...      ...     a2    ...        1           1
 ...      ...     a2    ...        1           1
 ...      ...     a3    ...        0           1
 ...      ...     a3    ...        0           1
 ...      ...     a3    ...        0           1
 ...      ...     a4    ...        1           1
 ...      ...     a4    ...        1           1
 ...      ...     a4    ...        1           1
```

Comment: You need to create a small dataset with dictionarys as a test case.

Comment: Trying to understand if I am getting this correct, based on `dict_1` and `dict_2` it seems `a1=0`, `a2=1`, `a3=1` and `a4=1`. Then in result `df` why is the value of `a1=1` in column `new_col_2` and not `a1=0`. Also, why is the value of `a3=0` in `new_col_2` and so on. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @NileshIngle it's a little confusing, but I think the idea is that `dict_2` represents values in separate columns, so the first entry in that dict indicates `newcol1 = 0, newcol2 = 1`,while  `dict_1` indicates which ids should have those columns filled in that way. So since both a1 and a3 have the same key as the first entry in `dict_2` they both get `newcol1 = 0, newcol2 = 1`

Comment: @ALollz: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, the keys in your two dictionaries are aligned. One way is to create a dataframe with a column id containing the values in `dict_1` and 2 (in this case but can be more) columns from the values in `dict_2` aligned on the same key. Then use `merge` on id to get the result back in `df`

```
# the two dictionaries. note in dict_2 I added an element for the list in key 2
# to show it works for any number of columns
dict_1 = {1:['a1', 'a3'],2:['a2', 'a4'],}
dict_2 = {1:[0,1],2:[1,1,2]} 

#create a dataframe from dict_2, here it might be something easier but can't find it
df_2 = pd.concat([pd.Series(vals, name=key) 
                  for key, vals in dict_2.items()], axis=1).T
print(df_2) #index are the keys, and columns are the future new_col_x
     0    1    2
1  0.0  1.0  NaN
2  1.0  1.0  2.0

#concat with the dict_1 once explode the values in the list, 
# here just a print to see what it's doing
print (pd.concat([pd.Series(dict_1, name='id').explode(),df_2], axis=1))
   id    0    1    2
1  a1  0.0  1.0  NaN
1  a3  0.0  1.0  NaN
2  a2  1.0  1.0  2.0
2  a4  1.0  1.0  2.0

# use previous concat, with a rename to change column names and merge to df
df = df.merge(pd.concat([pd.Series(dict_1, name='id').explode(),df_2], axis=1)
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'new_col_{x+1}' 
                                          if isinstance(x, int) else x), 
              on='id', how='left')
```

and you get

```
print (df)
   col_1 col_2  id col_3  new_col_1  new_col_2  new_col_3
0    100   500  a1   478        0.0        1.0        NaN
1    785   400  a1   490        0.0        1.0        NaN
2    ...   ...  a1   ...        0.0        1.0        NaN
3    ...   ...  a2   ...        1.0        1.0        2.0
4    ...   ...  a2   ...        1.0        1.0        2.0
5    ...   ...  a2   ...        1.0        1.0        2.0
6    ...   ...  a3   ...        0.0        1.0        NaN
7    ...   ...  a3   ...        0.0        1.0        NaN
8    ...   ...  a3   ...        0.0        1.0        NaN
9    ...   ...  a4   ...        1.0        1.0        2.0
10   ...   ...  a4   ...        1.0        1.0        2.0
11   ...   ...  a4   ...        1.0        1.0        2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us try `explode` with `map`

```
s=pd.Series(dict_1).explode().reset_index()
s.columns=[1,2]
df['new_1']=df.id.map(dict(zip(s[2],s[1])))

#s=pd.Series(dict_2).explode().reset_index()
#s.columns=[1,2]
#df['new_2']=df.id.map(dict(zip(s[2],s[1])))
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, also it's not getting the values from `dict_2` which need to be added to the `df`

Comment: I think you're not getting the question correctly. I am trying to use the keys from the 2 dictionaries to compare between them and then use the values for each key from `dict_1` and `df` to add the values of `dict_2` into the `df`.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have *'n values from the lists of dict_2 and want to construct n new columns in `df`'* such as

```
dict_2 = {1: [0, 1], 2: [1, 1, 6, 9]}
```

Using dict comprehension to construct a new dictionary from `dict_2` and `dict_1` and use it to construct a new dataframe with `orient='index'`. Chaining `rename` and `add_prefix`. Finally, merge it back to `df` with option `left_on='id', right_index=True`

```
key_dict = {x: v for k, v in dict_2.items() for x in dict_1[k]}

df_add = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(key_dict, orient='index')
                      .rename(lambda x: int(x)+1, axis=1).add_prefix('newcol_'))
    
df_final = df.merge(df_add, left_on='id', right_index=True)

Out[33]:
   col_1 col_2  id col_3  newcol_1  newcol_2  newcol_3  newcol_4
0    100   500  a1   478         0         1       NaN       NaN
1    785   400  a1   490         0         1       NaN       NaN
2    ...   ...  a1   ...         0         1       NaN       NaN
3    ...   ...  a2   ...         1         1       6.0       9.0
4    ...   ...  a2   ...         1         1       6.0       9.0
5    ...   ...  a2   ...         1         1       6.0       9.0
6    ...   ...  a3   ...         0         1       NaN       NaN
7    ...   ...  a3   ...         0         1       NaN       NaN
8    ...   ...  a3   ...         0         1       NaN       NaN
9    ...   ...  a4   ...         1         1       6.0       9.0
10   ...   ...  a4   ...         1         1       6.0       9.0
11   ...   ...  a4   ...         1         1       6.0       9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Construct a DataFrame that combines both of the dicts along the keys. Use the `DataFrame.from_dict` constructor and pandas will deal with the alignment on keys.

Then use `wide_to_long` to reshape it so that each `'id'` in `dict_1` gets linked with all of the columns in `dict_2`. Then this is a simple merge to join back to the original.

#### Sample Data

```
dict_1 = {1: ['a1', 'a3'], 2: ['a2', 'a4']}
dict_2 = {1: [0, 1], 2: [1, 1, 2]}
```

#### Code

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_1, orient='index').add_prefix('id'),
                 pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_2, orient='index').add_prefix('new_col')], axis=1)
#  id0 id1  new_col0  new_col1  new_col2
#1  a1  a3         0         1       NaN
#2  a2  a4         1         1       2.0

df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df1, i=[x for x in df1.columns if 'new_col' in x],
                       j='will_drop', stubnames=['id'])
         .reset_index().drop(columns='will_drop'))
#   new_col0  new_col1  new_col2  id
#0         0         1       NaN  a1
#1         0         1       NaN  a3
#2         1         1       2.0  a2
#3         1         1       2.0  a4

df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
```

---

```
   col_1 col_2  id col_3  new_col0  new_col1  new_col2
0    100   500  a1   478         0         1       NaN
1    785   400  a1   490         0         1       NaN
2    ...   ...  a1   ...         0         1       NaN
3    ...   ...  a2   ...         1         1       2.0
4    ...   ...  a2   ...         1         1       2.0
5    ...   ...  a2   ...         1         1       2.0
6    ...   ...  a3   ...         0         1       NaN
7    ...   ...  a3   ...         0         1       NaN
8    ...   ...  a3   ...         0         1       NaN
9    ...   ...  a4   ...         1         1       2.0
10   ...   ...  a4   ...         1         1       2.0
11   ...   ...  a4   ...         1         1       2.0
```